# Input fields become disable?

Tags: html, css, angular8

I designed a register form.

But on applying float:left and right on inputs in form,

The input fields become disable.

How is this happens?

How I avoid it?

Please suggest some answer. Thanks in advance

```css
.content-left {
    margin: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
    float:left;
    clear: left;
}

.content-right {
    margin: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
    float:right;
    clear: right;
}

.form-group {
    width: 100vw - 16.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay border-0">
        <span class="title-head">Add Trainee</span>
        <div class="row">
            <form [formGroup]='regForm' class="form-group" (ngSubmit)="uploadForm(regForm)" >
                <div class="content-left col-md-6">
                    <span class="tra-header"><b>Trainee Name</b></span><br/>
                    <input class="tra-name col-6" type="text" formControlName="traineeName"/>
                </div>
                <div class="content-right col-md-6">
                    <span class="tra-header"><b>Trainee Email ID</b></span><br/>
                    <input class="tra-name col-6" type="email" formControlName="traineeEmail"/>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-toolbar ml-3 mt-3">
                    <div class="btn-group mr-3">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need more info. Are you using Bootsrap? What version?

Comment: i m using bootstarap version 4

Comment: As you can see [here](https://codepen.io/aruizh/pen/GRoLzEO) with the info you provide, everything works normally. May be it is a conflict with angular and bootstrap.

Comment: I solved  it by using grid basics